# Debugging A Conditional If Chain

Tags: r, conditional-statements, scatter-plot, chain

I am trying to create a scatterplot and color the points within the specified ranges differently. I feel as though this chain should work, where I state the condition and the desired color in brackets.

Can anyone spot an error in my approach? or potentially the syntax?

```
plot(x, y, xlab="chr X position (Mb)",
     ylab="Diversity", pch=16, cex=0.7,
     col=if(x < 4), {"red"}
          else {
            if((x>3)&(x<89)) {"black"}
            else {
              if((x>88)&(x<94)) {"blue"}
              }
            else {
              if((x>93)&(x<155)) {"black"}
              }
            else {
              if(x>154) {"purple"}
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ifelse`

```
col = ifelse(x<4, "red",
       ifelse(x>3 & x<89 | x>93 & x<155, "black",
              ifelse(x>88 & x<94, "blue", "purple")))
```

You need `ifelse` becase `ifelse` is vectorized, `if` is not, therefore `ifelse` will check each element in your vector and filled with the corresponding color, while `if` only checks for the first element.

A simple example to note this:

```
x <- 1:6  # a sample vector

# using `if` to check condition and assigning a value, it'll fail 
if(x<4){
  "red"
} else {
  "other color"
}

# suing `ifelse` for the same task. It'll win
ifelse(x<4, "red", "other color")
```

from the helpfile

> `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 4):

Your code is ugly! Use `cut` to convert your numeric values into a categorical 'factor' object, then set the colours.

```
> x=sample(1:20)
> x
 [1]  5  1  9 17  2  6  4  3  8 13 16 10 11 20 18 19 12 14  7 15
> f = cut(x,breaks=c(0,5,13,21)) # choose your breaks here
> f
 [1] (0,5]   (0,5]   (5,13]  (13,21] (0,5]   (5,13]  (0,5]   (0,5]   (5,13] 
[10] (5,13]  (13,21] (5,13]  (5,13]  (13,21] (13,21] (13,21] (5,13]  (13,21]
[19] (5,13]  (13,21]
Levels: (0,5] (5,13] (13,21]
> levels(f)=c("red","green","purple")
> plot(x,col=as.character(f),pch=19)
```

That should plot the low points in red, the middle in green, the top in purple.

For extra points, write a function that takes your values, your breaks, and a vector of colours and does the colour mapping for you. Then you just do:

```
> plot(x, col=colourMap(x,breaks = c(0,5,13,21), colours = c("red","green","purple")))
```